# Book about an orphaned Welsh space pirate in a high-gravity world who later visits Wales

Tags: story-identification, books, pirates

About thirty years ago, I read a book about a Welsh boy orphaned in a high-gravity world of pirates. He grew up to become one of them, and later in the story, he visited Wales to explore his origins. Can't remember the name of it for the life of me.

Comment: It's too recent, but it does sound a bit like "Jabin"

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! Please consider [registering](/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827) to more features of the site. Unregistered users are not able to vote, and they would not be able to respond to or edit posts made under the same username on another device or browser, or when their browser cookies are cleared. Registering an account is easy, and it will allow you to participate more fully in our community.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't ten years ago not thirty, because Clara's suggestion of [Jabin](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22462025-jabin) is exactly like your description.

Comment: Does *Jabin* have a high gravity planet @JohnRennie ?  I don't recall (and the reviews don't seem to mention it).

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez I looked for a copy but couldn't find one so I'm not sure, but how many books can there be about orphans from (New South) Wales joining pirates? :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie It's also a stretch from 10 years to 30, but I'll take a punt

Answer (score 5):

*Starwolf* trilogy by Edmond Hamilton.

From the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starwolf_(novel_series)) the books are:

- *The Weapon from Beyond* (1967)
- *The Closed Worlds* (1968)
- *World of the Starwolves* (1968)

I read the books sometime in the 1980s. The boy (of Welsh descent) was orphaned on a high gravity planet and brought up by the space raider alien vikings/pirates there.  The pirates were so successful because they could withstand high G forces and so could outmanoeuvre their victims.  Morgan (the human boy) is one of them till some disagreement forces him to leave.

Other things I remember.  Morgan does visit Wales and learns to sing (badly).  He joins a Terran mercenary company, whose captain normally seems ineffective until things get bad where he suddenly turns calm and competent.  Also Earth is poor because it is in a solar system with only one habitable planet (which is unusual in the setting).

It was a long time ago, so I remember bits and pieces rather than the whole.

Comment: The first few chapters are available to read for free on [Baen's website](https://www.baen.com/Chapters/1299450172/1299450172.htm).

Comment: Note that while the original books are from the 1960s, there was an [omnibus edition](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?30909) released in 1982 (and subsequently reprinted through 1990).  Since the detail about going to Wales is from *The Closed Worlds*, I suspect OP read the omnibus, *Starwolf*.

Comment: Probably.  I must have read the UK 1985 Ventura release.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to suggest *[Jabin](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22462025-jabin)*, also known as J*abin and the Space Pirates*, a novel from 2012 by Bev Allen.

The central character, the titular Jabin, is a teenager who is orphaned, and leads a fairly miserable life being passed from relative to relative in the space colony of New Wales. The cover blurb summarises the plot as:

> In the space colony of New Wales, the pirate attacks are both
> relentless and merciless. Having lost both his parents, Jabin has been
> adopted by his austere and spiteful uncle and aunt who live in the
> space colony of New Wales which is riven with religious and political
> rivalry, and prey to the vicious maraudings of pirates whose cruelty
> and greed are beyond all imagination. When Jabin volunteers to
> surrender himself to a pirate raiding party to save a friend, he does
> so believing that nothing can be worse than his current suffering.
> However, he is soon to discover that things can always get worse when
> the stakes are high, the rewards are vast and slave labour is there
> for the taking. When the King of New Wales is assassinated, the colony
> threatens to collapse into total anarchy, leaving the pirates free
> reign to mutilate, kill and profit as they will, but the forces of law
> and order sent out from Earth are getting ready to fight back, and
> Jabin could have a vital part to play in the ensuing war if he can
> only stay alive.

So this book indeed involves an orphaned Welsh boy who becomes a space pirate. However I do not recall if New Wales was a high gravity world, or the story ended with him going to (old) Wales. There is also the fact that the book was published ten years ago, rather than thirty. But in view of how well it fits the other points, I'm putting it forward as a candidate.